# Optimal compression method for Android devices

Tags: python, python-2.7, compression

I am developing an application that requires zipping up a file on a server and compressed file to an Android Mobile device. The server will be compressing the file using a python script. What is the recommended compression method that will be the fastest most suitable for sending a compressed file to an Android device and decompressing the file on the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest would be [zlib.compress](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) at level 1.  I don't know what you mean by "most suitable".

Comment: Sorry for the amiguity. By most suitable, I mean is there a recommended compression method that works best for decompressing files on the android end in terms of power efficiency and speed.

Comment: Also zlib decompression is very fast.  You could also look at lz4, which is faster still with less compression.  You would need to compile it yourself and link it to python.  https://github.com/steeve/python-lz4